# Combine several objects with weird structure into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with a few objects which I'm trying to combine into one single object

```js
[
  { user: { '563D': { pId: '12', seasion: '120', value: true } } },
  { user: { '563D': { pId: '11', seasion: '120', value: false } } },
  ...
]
```

- `pId` is unique
- `seasion` is the same for each object (almost never changing)
- `value` can be anything

I want to have something like this:

```js
{
  id: '563D',
  seasion: '120',
  types: {
    12: // pId
    {
      value: true
    },
    11:
    {
      value: false
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use reduce and forEach but I wasnt been able to achieve my goals
due to poor understanding of those 2 methods.

***EDIT***:

forgot about several users input, sorry

```js
[
  {
    users: {
      '563D': [Object],
      '4b07': [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    users: {
      '563D': [Object],
      '4b07': [Object]
    }
  },
  {
   users: {
      '563D': [Object],
      '4b07': [Object]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: is `[Object]` the placeholer for the same named part? please add the original data. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz edited my questing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to group the objects based on the first key inside `user`. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the array of each group values:

- Get `user` from each object by destructuring the parameter
- Destructure the first [entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the `user` to get the key (like `'563D'`) and the nested properties separately)
- Use the `||` operator to check if the accumulator already has the `id` as it's property. If yes, use it. Else assign a new value with `{ id, seasion, types: {} }`. This is using the [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).
- Update the `types` with `pId` as key and `{ value }` as it's value

```js
const input = [{user:{'563D':{pId:'12',seasion:120,value:true}, '4b07':{pId:'12',seasion:120,value:true}}},{user:{'563D':{pId:'11',seasion:120,value:false},'4b07':{pId:'11',seasion:120,value:false}}}]

const output = input.reduce((r, { user }) => {
  for(const [id, { pId, seasion, value }] of Object.entries(user)) {
    r[id] = r[id] || { id, seasion, types: {} };
    r[id].types[pId] = { value };
  }
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(output))
```

If you have only one unique `id` in the array, you can simplify the `reduce` to:

```js
const input = [{user:{'563D':{pId:'12',seasion:120,value:true}}},{user:{'563D':{pId:'11',seasion:120,value:false}}}]

const output = input.reduce((r, { user }) => {
  const [id, { pId, seasion, value }] = Object.entries(user)[0];
  return { id, seasion, types: { ...r.types, [pId]: { value } } }
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: can you please explain this part of code `r[id] = r[id] || { id, season, types: {} };` 
i dont really understand what happening there

Comment: @Gordie that's the OR operator. If the accumulator already has the `id` as key, use it. Else, add a new `id` property with `{ id, seasion, types: {} }` as value

Comment: Is `563D` the only key inside all `user` object? or you have other possible values

Comment: so what is a best way to rename keys inside of types[pId] obj, for example I want to rename `value` to `notValue` but keep value of `value`, sorry for choosing bad name for dummy keys

Comment: @Gordie added another approach for only one unique `id`.

Comment: @Gordie you can simply use `{ notValue: value }` instead of `{ value }`

Comment: okay, I figure out in my own, feel pretty dumn now, thx, I will try another approach as well

Comment: Edited my questing again, forgot to mention important part, sorryyy

Comment: @Gordie Add breakpoints and please understand how the answer works. Instead of `Object.entries(user)[0]` you just need to loop through `Object.entries(user)` and update accumulator from the first answer. I've already changed and explained the answer several times. Just because we don't charge for it, doesn't mean our time is free. I'm not answering the ever moving goalposts of your question. Please create a [mcve] with all the details from next time

Comment: @Gordie I have updated the answer for your new requirement

Comment: I see how it is, sorry I never made i post here before, I will try do better next time I would need help, thank you so much for your time, you really did helped me.